# set path for python command in shell(mac)

Tags: python, pythonpath

I want to run python command as follows, without the whole path of pyahp or other scripts. It reported the error. I have to add the whole path, ie .../site_packages/ that is tedious. How can I run it directly?

```
[~] python pyahp                                                      
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'pyahp': 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I trid to add pythonpath, however it failed.

> export
>   PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib"

Comment: Have you added a python PATH? See the below from superuser:
https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path

Comment: @BenP mine is mac